# Generic approach to create flow charts in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, flowchart

I have to create an animated flow chart GUI which displays different states. Further on demand the flow chart elements are re-positioned and re-sized if the focus shifts to certain elements.

All of this is no problem, with drawing shapes, animations, etc. provided by WPF this is an easy, though by hand and alot of manually is done.

The problem I am facing is, that there will be > 40 of these flow charts.

Is there a template mechanism or generic approach to generalize this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a set of user controls is the right way to deal with this problem.

The advantage is, animation and design can be encapsulated into the user control files. This way they don't polute the main application code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a project called Graph# http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/ an there must be similar projects on codeplex.

Comment: @Akash-kava the graph library let you model only very general elements. I need high customization for every element.